# ¿Cómo corrijo el error "Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file... but no encoding declared"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, codificación

Estoy usando Python 2.7 para correr un programa que está en Python 3.6. Lo agregué a los interpretadores pero aún me aparece este error:

> File "/Users/a/Desktop/proyecto porgramacion 2/proyecto.py", line 17
>   SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /Users/a/Desktop/proyecto porgramacion 2/proyecto.py on line 17, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Answer (score 4):

Tu módulo (el archivo .py) no usa ASCII como [codificación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codificaci%C3%B3n_de_caracteres) sino UTF-8 (dado que no se define otro encoding y asumo que funciona en Python 3) y contiene caracteres no-ASCII.

**El intérprete en Python 3 usa UTF-8 como codificación por defecto para el código fuente, mientras que Python 2 usa ASCII** por defecto. Cuando el intérprete de Python 2 se encuentra con un carácter no ASCII no sabe cómo interpretarlo al no tener información de la codificación que debe usar y lanza la excepción que muestras:

> Error de sintaxis: Carácter No-ASCII  '\xe2' en fichero /Users/a/Desktop/proyecto porgramacion 2/proyecto.py en línea 17, pero codificación no declarada;

Tal y como el propio error te informa, debes declarar la codificación en la primera o segunda línea del archivo como se especifica en [PEP 263 -- Defining Python Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Esto informa al intérprete de que debe tratar el código fuente como UTF-8 (o cualquier otra codificación si se diera el caso) y no como ASCII, pudiendo usar literales de cadena, identificadores, comentarios, etc que contengan caracteres fuera de la tabla ASCII. Esto debe hacerse obligatoriamente tanto en Python 2 como en Python 3 cuando se quiera usar una codificación para el código fuente distinta a la que el intérprete usa por defecto.